# Transitive dependencies in maven plugins

Tags: dependencies, maven-plugin, transitivity

Are dependencies in Maven plugins supposed to resolve their transitive dependencies or do they have to be manually added to the plugin dependencies?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Normal transitive dependency rules apply to maven plugins. You can further override existing plugin dependencies or add to the classpath seen by a plugin in your project's pom using that plugin's configuration - adding a dependencies section. An example can be seen [here](http://www.sonatype.com/books/maven-book/reference/optimizing-sect-plugins.html).

Comment: Perhaps this is the updated [link](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/_configuring_maven_plugins.html#_adding_plugin_dependencies)